# Continuous reading mode in TexWorks built-in pdf viewer?

Tags: texworks

I recently downloaded TeX Live 2013 to use LaTeX on my Windows 7 machine. I like the interface of the TeXworks editor that came with it because it is similar to TeXShop that I like a lot when I am using my office Mac, so I wanted something similar for my (Windows) home machine. It works great except that I cannot use its built-in PDF viewer in a continuous scroll mode. As I scroll down, at the end of each page it stops, and needs an extra scroll to jump to the next page, without the ability of showing the bottom of the previous page and the top of the new page at the same time. I could use another PDF viewer like acrobat but I think they do not support sync between the TeX document that created it so that I ctrl+click one to jump to the corresponding paragraph in the other, which is a big convenience that I don't want to give up either. Is there a way to configure TeX Live/TeXworks in a way to have continuous pdf view mode?

Comment: There is a [corresponding feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=617&q=type%3DEnhancement&sort=-id). But since development somehow stagnates, this can take a while. That said, I think this question is off topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible in TeXworks at the moment, the viewer doesn't support it. There is an open feature request (https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/617), and there are plans to include it in the  next major release of TeX works (0.6): https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still present in 2016, TeXworks version 0.4.6-3.10.
I use a **workaround** which makes it a bit more tolerable:

Scale down the preview size so that one whole page fits into the window. Then one can cycle through the document without interruptions. The trade-off is a reduction in size/readability of the preview.

This can be done under Edit -> Settings -> Preview. In this menu, change the value for "fixed enlargement" to something below 100% until the page fits. One probably needs to restart the program to see the effect.

Note that I may have gotten the menu names wrong in these instructions, b.c. I'm using a German interface. It should be obvious, though, what is meant.